# How to get the MAC address of an Ethernet shield, if it is not printed on it?

Tags: arduino-uno

Help me to find out how to connect an Ethernet shield over the internet using a LAN cable. I have tried many times but I'm not getting a MAC and IP address.

Comment: The MAC address is written to the Ethernet Controller.  The IP address can be given by DHCP or static in which it is also written to the Controller.

Comment: Have you read ["Getting Started with the Arduino Ethernet Shield"](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoEthernetShield) and the ["Arduino Ethernet+SD"](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/ethfiles.html) section of Lady Ada's Arduino Tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a MAC address then you have to make one up.  There are a couple of rules and regulations about what a MAC address can be, but most of the time you can just make one up:

1. It must be unique on *your* network
2. There are a set of prefixes that are reserved for special purposes:

   - The lowest bit of the first byte must be 0
   - The second bit of the first byte must be 1

You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Once you have provided a MAC address and physically connected it to the network then you need an IP address and netmask.  There are two ways you can get the IP address and netmask:

1. Through DHCP - For example your home internet router would provide the IP address for you.
2. By allocating your own. This must be within the range of your network's IP addresses, typically something like 192.168.0.x where x is between 1 and 255.  The IP address must be unique on your network.

The netmask, again, can be given by DHCP, otherwise you will have to enter the netmask of your network, typically 255.255.255.0

Then to access the internet itself you need to provide (or be provided with through DHCP) the address of the internet gateway and possibly a DNS server address. On a home network they are typically the address of the router, which may well be 192.168.0.1 or something similar.

Comment: Specifically, it is setting the second lowest bit of the highest octet to 1 which indicates a locally administered or "made it up yourself" address.